# Which GitHub repo for RxJS docs?

Tags: rxjs, pull-request

I want to create a PR for the RxJS docs
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

But don't see which repo is associated with the docs.

I looked in the RxJS GitHub repo in the docs folder, but I couldn't find the docs that are used for this page/site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the location [repo link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/doc)

> These files are not meant for reading directly in GitHub, they are just source code for generating the official page. You should find the docs at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/, containing all the documentation.

It appears that they use esdoc to generate the docs. If you read through the readme.md you'll find a bit about [Adding Documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#adding-documentation).

So I'd image you'll have to update the comments within the code. I've no clue what portion you're wanting to update, but maybe something in [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts)

Comment: Nope - I already looked there. The page I'm looking for doesn't exist in that repo.

Comment: You should have verified that was the correct repo instead of guessing...

Comment: It is the correct repo. Also, it helps people help you when you've disclosed things you've tried before.

Comment: @Ed.S. The file doesn't exist because it gets generated by esdoc which consumes the code comments and produces the reference. All the operators are individually annotated so you will have to update the one you are interested in. You can see the generated files in the gh-pages.

Comment: @subhaze, thanks for the edit to your answer - that works for me.